# Anything wiki-like for Plone4

Tags: wiki, plone, document-management, knowledge-management

I'm trying to figure out a way to make a document management/knowledge management portal using Plone4. We really like idea of having a Wiki as a section of our site or, better yet, as a type of document in every space but with wiki-style linking and even preferably with wiki style editing (plaintext with wiki markup, but parsed to rich html on display).

Anyway, what I'm hoping for is some pointers to documentation, extensions and/or literature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I wrote in the previous question you created, Plone 3 and 4 have native support for Wiki-style editing. It only needs to be enabled: http://plone.org/documentation/faq/how-do-i-enable-wiki-style-markup

You can customize the default WYSIWYG editor (TinyMCE) in the Plone Control Panel in order to reduce and enable the available formatting options (buttons).

Answer (score 3):

Unless you by Wiki-style editing mean using a painful weird syntax instead of the visual editor people are used to, i'd stay away from that thing called Wicked. Your users don't need that.

For what most people mean by Wiki, an area where everyone can edit content, just use the "sharing" tab and grant all logged in members the power to create and edit content.

:)

Comment: Actually what I had in mind is ability to simply do [[Article Title]] style link and such. In my mind wiki is not (only) about shared editing but also fast, simple hyperlinking of local content.

Comment: As Baekholt said, it's pretty fast and simple to hyperlink inside normal Plone pages. Wicked would give you ((the desired hyperlinking syntax)) though. That makes it easier to point to still non-existent pages, wiki-like. Baekholt, do you see anything specific against Wicked or just the overhead of the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just a pointer to a bug :(... that would prevent you to use non ascii characters in the title of the pages to be created
http://dev.plone.org/plone/ticket/11212 (if you are running Plone 4: I don't know for Plone 3)